# reverting restricted system modules in python notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin

I have this `sys.modules['os']=None` in my python notebook. It restricts importing `os` module. Now if in another notebook, i want to access it, is there a way to revert that statement in current notebook.